# How to rebuild docker container in docker-compose.yml?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-container

There are scope of services which are defined in docker-compose.yml. These services have been started. I need to rebuild only one of these and start it without up other services.
I run the following commands:

```
docker-compose up -d # run all services
docker-compose stop nginx # stop only one. but it is still running !!!
docker-compose build --no-cache nginx 
docker-compose up -d --no-deps # link nginx to other services
```

At the end I get the old nginx container.
Docker-compose doesn't kill all running containers!

Comment: `docker-compose up --build`

Comment: Just to clarify upper comment: `docker-compose up --build` rebuild all containers. Use `docker-compose up --build <service_name>` as stated in @denov comment.

Comment: `docker-compose up --build <service_name>` does not work if you have a docker-compose.yml with containers coming from a container-registry

Comment: `docker-compose build --no-cache` when you want to build from the first level.

Comment: Should be easy to get these semantics straight (not you @yuklia - the compose team). Not sure why we still struggle with this in this millennium.

Comment: --build --force-recreate --no-deps don't rebuild :S on latest version. compare images before and after, are the same!

Comment: Pull the image you want to rebuild first. Unless you specify this (using pull_policy: always) in your docker-compose file, docker-compose will just rebuild the existing image.

Answer (score 783):

[docker-compose up](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

```
$ docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```

or newer versions of docker

```
$ docker compose up -d --no-deps --build <service_name>
```

> --no-deps - Don't start linked services.

> --build - Build images before starting containers.

Comment: @evgpisarchik The orders a bit out, it should be `docker-compose build --no-cache service1 service2`

Comment: why y'all talking about service? the question was to rebuild container not service

Comment: @temirbek container inside compose is defined under `services` block

Answer (score 489):

With docker-compose 1.19 [`up`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate --no-deps [-d] [<service_name>..]
```

Without one or more `service_name` arguments all images will be built if missing and all containers will be recreated.

From the help menu

```
Options:
    -d, --detach        Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                        print new container names. Incompatible with
                        --abort-on-container-exit.
    --no-deps           Don't start linked services.
    --force-recreate    Recreate containers even if their configuration
                        and image haven't changed.
    --build             Build images before starting containers.
```

### Without cache

To force a rebuild to ignore cached layers, we have to first [build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/build/) a new image

```
docker-compose build --no-cache [<service_name>..]
```

From the help menu

```
Options:
    --force-rm              Always remove intermediate containers.
    -m, --memory MEM        Set memory limit for the build container.
    --no-cache              Do not use cache when building the image.
    --no-rm                 Do not remove intermediate containers after a successful build.
```

Then recreate the container

```
docker-compose up --force-recreate --no-deps [-d] [<service_name>..]
```

Comment: I'm confused how this answers the question. How do we rebuild just the one container?

Comment: You can rebuild only one container by appending it's name to the end of the command. `docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --build container_name`

Comment: Wait a sec, this *recreates **container***, it is not equivalent to `build --no-cache` option, unless the command description is completely wrong

Comment: what exactly does 'Dont start lined services' mean?

Answer (score 93):

This should fix your problem:

```bash
docker-compose ps # lists all services (id, name)
docker-compose stop <id/name> #this will stop only the selected container
docker-compose rm <id/name> # this will remove the docker container permanently 
docker-compose up # builds/rebuilds all not already built container
```

Comment: if you want to `stop` and `rm` all containers then you can use the command `docker-compose down`.  Your solution is better if you only want to get rid of some.

Comment: This solution is a good fit for the setup where you don't want to stop the entire docker application and just recreate one of the services

Comment: I needed to actually run `docker-compose build <id/name>` before `up` to rebuild the changed Dockerfile.

Comment: but then you are stopping a live container, which isn't really feasible for a live site.

Answer (score 74):

As @HarlemSquirrel posted, it is the best and I think the correct solution.

But, to answer the OP specific problem, it should be something like the following command, as he doesn't want to recreate ALL services in the `docker-compose.yml` file, but only the `nginx` one:

```
docker-compose up -d --force-recreate --no-deps --build nginx
```

Options description:

```
Options:
  -d                  Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
                      print new container names. Incompatible with
                      --abort-on-container-exit.
  --force-recreate    Recreate containers even if their configuration
                      and image haven't changed.
  --build             Build images before starting containers.
  --no-deps           Don't start linked services.
```

Answer (score 23):

Maybe these steps are not quite correct, but I do like this:

stop docker compose: `$ docker-compose down`

WARNING: The following `prune -a` will delete all images, you may not want this as it could effect other projects. you can read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

remove the container: `$ docker system prune -a`

start docker compose: `$ docker-compose up -d`

Comment: `docker system prune -a` will delete all images, even ones for other projects. I would recommend against using this.

Comment: aL_eX, flag -a (means all) you can select only the one you need by specifying its id

Comment: @aL_eX I agree this method is somewhat dangerous. But this is working for sure. Other answers do not remove images.

Comment: I edited your answer, adding a warning. <3. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: Brandon Bertelsen, ok, but to remove all images use  -a  (--all) - "Remove all unused images not just dangling ones"

Comment: prune -a is a bit of an overkill here, no? Like killing an ant with a nuke..

Answer (score 11):

```
docker-compose stop nginx # stop if running
docker-compose rm -f nginx # remove without confirmation
docker-compose build nginx # build
docker-compose up -d nginx # create and start in background
```

Removing container with rm is essential. Without removing, Docker will start old container.

Answer (score 8):

For me it only fetched new dependencies from Docker Hub with both `--no-cache` and `--pull` (which are available for `docker-compose build`.

```sh
# other steps before rebuild
docker-compose build --no-cache --pull nginx # rebuild nginx
# other steps after rebuild, e.g. up (see other answers)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```bash
docker-compose build
```

And if you are using a docker profile:

```bash
docker-compose --profile profile_name build
```

Comment: The fastest and easiest way to rebuild all your containers!

Answer (score 7):

Simply use :

```
docker-compose build [yml_service_name]
```

Replace `[yml_service_name]` with your service name in `docker-compose.yml` file. You can use `docker-compose restart` to make sure changes are effected. You can use `--no-cache` to ignore the cache.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is:

```
$ docker-compose stop nginx
```

didn't work (you said it is still running). If you are going to rebuild it anyway, you can try killing it:

```
$ docker-compose kill nginx
```

If it still doesn't work, try to stop it with docker directly:

```
$ docker stop nginx
```

or delete it

```
$ docker rm -f nginx
```

If that still doesn't work, check your version of docker, you might want to upgrade.

It might be a bug, you could check if one matches your system/version. Here are a couple, for ex:
https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10589

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/12738

As a workaround, you could try to kill the process.

```
$ ps aux | grep docker 
$ kill 225654 # example process id
```

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the image named nginx is defined in your docker-compose file. In this case, there is a key/value pair like this: `image: repo_name`.
If this is the case, I suggest pulling the newer image first with `docker pull repo_name`.
Then build the service `docker-compose build nginx`. This will then use the newly pulled image.
Then you can `docker-compose up -d nginx`.

As a matter of fact, you don't need to stop the container at all while doing this.

(And if you do this a lot, take the trouble to clean out old images occasionally: `docker image ls`, and then `docker image rm <id>`for all the images where the value for TAG is `<none>`. If the image should still be in used regardless, Docker will tell you.)

EDIT: `docker-compose stop` doesn't "kill" (remove) containers, it just stops them. They're still there somehow, sort of suspended. If you want to really kill, i.e. remove containers, use `docker-compose down` instead; you'll see from the output that this command really gets rid of the containers.

Answer (score 1):

```
docker image rm -f nginx
```

to remove the docker nginx and

```
docker-compose up -d
```

to recreate nginx while keeping the other services running

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're aiming to rebuild and restart only the nginx service in your Docker Compose setup without affecting other services.I proposed bash script accomplishes this task efficiently. Here's your proposed script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Check if the service name is provided
if [ -z "$1" ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <service_name>"
    exit 1
fi

# Stop the existing container of the specified service
docker-compose stop "$1"

# Rebuild the specified service
docker-compose build --no-cache "$1"

# Start only the specified service without starting linked services
docker-compose up -d --no-deps "$1"
```

You can save this script to a file, for example, `rebuild_service.sh`, make it executable using `chmod +x rebuild_service.sh`, and then use it to rebuild and restart a specific service in your Docker Compose setup by passing the service name as an argument, like so:

```
./rebuild_service.sh nginx
```

Just replace Nginx with the name of the service you want to rebuild and restart. This script ensures that only the specified service is affected, saving time and avoiding unnecessary restarts of other services.

Answer (score -14):

Only:

```
$ docker-compose restart [yml_service_name]
```

Comment: this will not build new changes. from the manual - If you make changes to your docker-compose.yml configuration these changes will not be reflected after running this command.