# Docker Compose Always Force Build for One Service

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is a section of my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.2"
services:
  cachable_service:
    image: my/cachable_service:x.x
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: cachable_service_Dockerfile

  service_in_development:
    image: my/service_in_development:latest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - cachable_service
```

How do I force only the image for the `service_in_development` to be always build from scratch so I get my latest code in there?

I've looked into the `cache_from` option in the `docker-compose` file reference, but I couldn't find any clear explanation on what exactly it does.

Clarifications:

In this question, I was asking about an option to force rebuild only specific services using an option in the `docker-compose.yml` file itself. But, if a commandline option let's me do this, I'd be happy with that as well for now.

Also, I'm talking about forcing a 'rebuild' of images. Not just 'recreation' of service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to rebuild docker container in docker-compose.yml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884991/how-to-rebuild-docker-container-in-docker-compose-yml)

Answer (score 1):

You can use command below to rebuild all images:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

to force rebuild one service:

```
docker-compose up --build --force-recreate service-name-here
```

More useful parameters in [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/)

> ```
> Usage: up [options] [--scale SERVICE=NUM...] [SERVICE...]
>
> Options:
>     -d, --detach               Detached mode: Run containers in the background,
>                                print new container names. Incompatible with
>                                --abort-on-container-exit.
>     --no-color                 Produce monochrome output.
>     --quiet-pull               Pull without printing progress information
>     --no-deps                  Don't start linked services.
>     --force-recreate           Recreate containers even if their configuration
>                                and image haven't changed.
>     --always-recreate-deps     Recreate dependent containers.
>                                Incompatible with --no-recreate.
>     --no-recreate              If containers already exist, don't recreate
>                                them. Incompatible with --force-recreate and -V.
>     --no-build                 Don't build an image, even if it's missing.
>     --no-start                 Don't start the services after creating them.
>     --build                    Build images before starting containers.
>     --abort-on-container-exit  Stops all containers if any container was
>                                stopped. Incompatible with -d.
>     -t, --timeout TIMEOUT      Use this timeout in seconds for container
>                                shutdown when attached or when containers are
>                                already running. (default: 10)
>     -V, --renew-anon-volumes   Recreate anonymous volumes instead of retrieving
>                                data from the previous containers.
>     --remove-orphans           Remove containers for services not defined
>                                in the Compose file.
>     --exit-code-from SERVICE   Return the exit code of the selected service
>                                container. Implies --abort-on-container-exit.
>     --scale SERVICE=NUM        Scale SERVICE to NUM instances. Overrides the
>                                `scale` setting in the Compose file if present.
> ```

Comment: When I use `docker-compose up --build --force-recreate service-name-here`, it's building all the containers despite my specifying a service name.

Comment: Maybe you have  linked services in the docker-compose.yml file. Add `--no-deps` option to avoid build linked services

Comment: You're right. In my effort to simplify the question, I had removed a `depends_on`. So, when I try `--no-deps`, it does indeed not build 'cachable_service'. However, it doesn't bring it up either. It just builds and brings up only 'service_in_development'. I would like it to still bring up 'cacheable_service'.

Comment: These are the two commands I have tried: `docker-compose up --build --no-deps --force-recreate service_in_development` and `docker-compose up --build --no-deps service_in_development`. Both of them had similar results.

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/6332#issuecomment-437143989. Docker Compose build images procedure takes into dependencies(that's how it works), so you should look for other solutions that will allow you to build single images. I read that `dobi` can do it: `dist-img - building a minimal image (that doesn’t contain build dependencies) for distributing an application.`.  I have never used it so I can't help in this topic - test it :)

Comment: Thank you! Perhaps this feature is just not available currently, but I think, given docker-compose is really intended for local development, this feature makes a lot of sense. I will try to open a feature request.