# compose up --build does not refresh/rebuild

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

[stackoverflow:compose rebuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884991/how-to-rebuild-docker-container-in-docker-compose-yml/42728416)

everyone is telling `docker composer up --build` does rebuild, however I simply add a

`console.log("example")` inside my `server.js`, it does not reflect after `docker compose up --build`

Also, everytime I made some changes in my source code and try to rebuild , it never success connect to mongo db anymore.

And I must run all following commands to rebuild (but I want to persist my data in docker as well)

```
docker compose down
docker container rm nodejs-elliot 
docker container rm mongodd
docker image prune -a
y
docker volume prune
y
docker network prune
y
docker system prune -a
y
docker compose up --build
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.6"
services:
  easy-notes-app:
    container_name: nodejs-elliot
    image: elliotching/elliot-nodejs
    restart: always
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3003:3000"
    links:
      - mongo
  mongo:
    container_name: mongodd
    image: mongo
    # network_mode: host
    ports:
      - "28017:27017"
    volumes:
      - "mongodb_for_elliot_nodejs:/data/db"
volumes:
  mongodb_for_elliot_nodejs:
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /
COPY ./package.json ./package.json
COPY . .

RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "node", "./server.js" ]
```

Comment: Why would you need to constantly run builds? Just use `docker-compose build` to build your image, and use `docker-compose up` (the "loose" compose command is still experimental, don't rely on it to actually work yet). And if you need to do things like rebuilding things inside docker: that's what you do inside docker. E.g. apt-get updates, pip updates, npm updates, etc. are all things you "just do in your image". You don't rebuild it, you just treat it as a VM and have it run whatever scripts/commands update what you need updated inside the VM.

Comment: yes, even wihtout `--build` it doesn't reflect my source code changes as well. Do I need to `docker push` before compose?

Comment: And if you use `docker-compose`, not `docker compose`> Because the new standalone "compose" command is _highly experimental_ and not guaranteed to work properly in the slightest.

Comment: The rebuild workflow described here is pretty typical.  Unlike a VM, a container only runs a single process, and it's very normal to delete and recreate the container if the code changes.